# How to mute external webpage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, mute

I am currently working on a **Chrome extension**. An **external webpage** is included in the **popup html** by using [iframe](http://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-3-loading-any-web-page-in-a-popup/). The webpage includes background music. What I want to do is to **mute the music in that external webpage**, but muting an external webpage in iframe seems illegal. So are there other ways to approach what I want to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "illegal"? What did you try already?

Comment: From the answer of this [link](http://www.quora.com/Iframes/How-can-I-mute-the-audio-source-of-an-html-page-embedded-in-an-iframe). Just wondering if there is any other way to solve this problem without using a proxy.

Comment: You can inject a content script into an iframe, as long as you have host permissions for the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the Url Box : chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting

and then ENABLE this and restart chrome, then after restarting chrome u will find that when you hover over the audio icon in chrome tab mute is available.

**Reference** : http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/mute-noisy-tabs-in-google-chrome-1683215637